# Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-development

No logro buildear mi aplicacion y ya he probado de todo, cambie `com.facebook.react:react-native:+` en android/app/build-gradle por `com.facebook.react:react-native:0.68.2` y nada, probe agregando, borrando, y editando el jcenter() de buil-gradle y tampoco.
Ya no se que mas probar.

Answer (score 1):

In your project directory go to android/build.gradle update this. it works for me.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter() --> comment this 
        gradlePluginPortal() --> add this. 
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal() --> add this
       //jcenter() --> comment this
}
```

}